# Заполнение таблицы из ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Работаю через MVC PHP Framework и мне нужно записывать данные из формы в таблицу БД. Данные записываются, но также в эту же таблицу мне нужно загружать картинку. Как максимально просто это реализовать ?

Есть такая html-форма

```
    <div class="input-form">
    <div class="tog">
        <!--Заголовок-->
        <div class="input-item">
            <input placeholder="Заголовок"
                   id="newsTitle" name="newsTitle" type="text">
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>


        <!--Превью-->
        <div class="wrap-custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png, .svg" />
            <label  for="image1">
                <span>Превью</span>
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </label>
        </div>

        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
                // Refs
                var $file = $(this),
                    $label = $file.next('label'),
                    $labelText = $label.find('span'),
                    labelDefault = $labelText.text();

                // When a new file is selected
                $file.on('change', function(event){
                    var fileName = $file.val().split( '\\' ).pop(),
                        tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                    //Check successfully selection
                    if( fileName ){
                        $label
                            .addClass('file-ok')
                            .css('background-image', 'url(' + tmppath + ')');
                        $labelText.text(fileName);
                    }else{
                        $label.removeClass('file-ok');
                        $labelText.text(labelDefault);
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="tog center">

        <!--Текст новости-->
        <div class="input-item">
            <textarea class="news-text"
                      id="newsText" name="newsText" type="text" placeholder="Текст новости..."></textarea>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-preview">
            <button  onclick="createNews()">Опубликовать</button>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax-запрос

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/admin/create-news/',
            data: {
                newsTitle: $("#newsTitle").val(),
                newsText: $("#newsText").val()
            },

            success(data)
            {
                window.location.href='/admin/news-page/1';
                alert('Новость добавлена!');
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

PHP обработчик и отправка в базу

```
    public function actionCreateNews()
{
        $newsTitle = $_POST['newsTitle'];
        $newsText = $_POST['newsText'];
        $db = Database::getConnection();
        $prepared = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news (news_title, news_date, news_text) VALUES (:newsTitle, NOW(), :newsText)");
        $prepared->bindParam(":newsTitle", $newsTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prepared->bindParam(":newsText", $newsText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prepared->execute();
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Укажите какой фреймворк используете. Логика у всех будет одна, реализация будет отличаться.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно создать отдельную папку у себя в проекте для хранения загруженных картинок, сохранять туда файл из формы, а в базу данных записывать только имя этого файла.

Comment: И это не только 'как вариант', это единственный вменяемый вариант для решения данной задачи